# How to use AppCompactActivity along with TabActivity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to implement this.Because i want to add toolbar with **TabHost**.But i am not able to do.How can use both activity? Toolbar can not use without use **AppCompactActivity**.Currenty i am using TabActivity.I extends TabActivity.But i also need to use AppCompactActivity.I know that we can not extends multiple class in java.Please help me.My code is below.

**main.xml**

```
  <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**tab_and_toolbar.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/main"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**AndroidTabAndListView.java**

```
    public class AndroidTabAndListView extends TabActivity {
    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String SITE = "Site PickUP";
    private static final String DOORSTEP= "Doorstep Delivery";
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.tab_and_toolbar);
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabSpec site = tabHost.newTabSpec(SITE);`
        // Tab Icon
        site.setIndicator(SITE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_inbox));
        Intent siteIntent = new Intent(this, SitePickupActivity.class);
        // Tab Content
        site.setContent(siteIntent);


        TabSpec doorstep = tabHost.newTabSpec(DOORSTEP);
        doorstep.setIndicator(DOORSTEP, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_outbox));
        Intent doorstepIntent = new Intent(this, DoorStepActivity.class);
        doorstep.setContent(doorstepIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(site); 
        tabHost.addTab(doorstep);

    }

}
```

Comment: you can use tablayout fillow this link [tab layout](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)

Comment: Thanks..But i want  tab with listview.i do not want to sweeping.

Comment: you can add listview in in my friend

Comment: Yes friend SitePickupActivity is Listview activity.So friend how can i extend appcompactactivity.Use toolbar in this activity.Pls help friendd.Thanks

Comment: i''ll advise you to use tablayout

Comment: ok..thanks..but i need TabHost.

Comment: I have found alternet solution for this.I used Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);toolbar.setIcon(R.Drawable.logo);toolbar.setTitle("Title_Name");I can not getSupportActionBar(toolbar).

Comment: that's why I told to use tab layout

Comment: welcome let me know if any query